# InnerHTML en Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un código el cual debería generar un innerHTML en IONIC pero IONIC al crear la etiqueta le ingresa contenido ejemplo:

```html
<ion-input class="incomesValue input input-md" placeholder="Ingreso 1" type="number" ng-reflect-placeholder="Ingreso 1" ng-reflect-type="number"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><input class="text-input text-input-md ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-klass="text-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="text-input-md" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="" type="number" placeholder="Ingreso 1" min="undefined" max="undefined" step="undefined" ng-reflect-placeholder="Ingreso 1" ng-reflect-type="number" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><input aria-hidden="true" next-input="" type="number"><button class="text-input-clear-icon disable-hover button button-md button-clear button-clear-md" clear="" ion-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-clear="" hidden=""><span class="button-inner"></span><div class="button-effect"></div></button><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="input-cover" tappable=""></div></ion-input>
```

Aparece esto:

```html
<ion-input type="text" class="incomesDesc" placeholder="Descripción"></ion-input>
```

Mi código javascript:

```js
function addRow(){
 var html_element = document.getElementById("newRowIncome");
 var htmlIncome = '<ion-row class="row">\n\
   <ion-col col-5>\n\
    <ion-input type="text" class="incomesDesc" placeholder="Descripción"></ion-input>\n\
   </ion-col>\n\
   <ion-col col-5>\n\
    <ion-input type="number" class="incomesValue" placeholder="Ingreso 1"></ion-input>\n\
   </ion-col>\n\
   <ion-col col-2>\n\
    <button ion-button item-right btn-md><ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon></button>\n\
   </ion-col>\n\
  </ion-row>';
 html_element.innerHTML = html_element.innerHTML + htmlIncome;
}
```

Muchas gracias si alguien tiene alguna solución, saludos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer, podrías explicarlo un poco mejor.

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por la respuesta, Tengo un formulario con un campo descrpción otro campo tipo numero y un botón que es para añadir una fila nueva, al dar click a ese botón se me crea el HTML en la nueva fila, pero no me crea los componentes de ionic

Comment: En teoria debería funcionar así como lo tienes :s

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la grid esta lista cuando se carga la app por ende carga los componentes pero cuando le doy clic al botón ese HTML IONIC no esta convertido y no tiene cargados los componentes

Comment: Y si pones ese HTML donde debe de ir en tu etiqueta contenedora en este caso newRowIncome y le pones este atributo [hidden]="esVisible" y pones en tu .ts public esVisible = false y en tu evento click le dices this.esVisible = true

Comment: Si, te entiendo, lo que pasa es que no hay determinado un numro total de filas, eso lo definiría el usuario :/

Comment: Pffff, estuve leyendo que no es posible hacer eso, igual y si lo pones en un modelo y lo recorres con un for

Comment: Dónde leíste ? pasame link porfa

Comment: si, estaba pensando en ponerlo en un ajax y la respuesta pintarla

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-dynamic-html-binding/49960/12 es que precisamente estoy trabajando con ionic 2 en un proyecto pero no me he topado con ese tipo de cosas me imagino que si me voy a topar con algo similar en un futuro :(

Comment: aunque este es ionic3, esperemos a ver que solución encontramos, si alguna cosa te pones en contacto conmigo.